# Meaning of "The UN rush to mandate war totally ruled out any alternatives."

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

I didn't get the exact meaning of the sentence;

> 1. "The UN rush to mandate war totally ruled out any alternatives.".

Can I paraphrase it as;

> 2. "The UN which rush to mandate war totally ruled out any alternatives."

Or;

> 3. "The UN let the war outbreak because there is another option."

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence can be logically split as follows:

- The UN rush

  - to mandate war *(which rush?)*
- totally ruled out

  - any alternatives. *(what did the rush rule out)*

---

Your sentence number 2 should be:

> "The UN which rush**ed** to mandate war totally ruled out any alternatives."

---

I think that your sentence 3 is not conveying the original meaning. The way I understand it, the original meaning is:

> The UN let the war outbreak **even though** there **might have been** <strike>an</strike>other option**s**.